# Regex to cut file name from URL

Tags: java, regex

I need to cut fileName form links like this:

```
 url('../webfonts/2EC49F_0_0.eot')
```

So I need to cut `'2EC49F'` path, I create this pattern:`([\/]].*?[_])`
But its doesn't work. I use Java Pattern/Matcher.

Comment: regex has different flavors - depends on the programming language you're using. Further, since what you're looking for is between the last `/` to the last dot - you don't *have to* use regex at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this

```
/.*?([^\/]*$)/
```

or

```
.*(?<=\/)([^_.]*).*$
```

That you can use `\1` substitution.

Comment: I need just cut '2EC49F' between '/' and before first '_'

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack I think second one is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookaround based regex for matching:

```
(?<=/)[^/_]+(?=_)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH8qG5/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern for the match:

```
([^_\/]*)_
```

and replace it with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, don't use regex. Instead:

```
String url(String input) {
    int slashLoc = input.lastIndexOf('/');
    int underLoc = input.indexOf('_', slashLoc);
    if (slashLoc != -1 && underLoc && slashLoc+1 < underLoc) { // sanity check
        return input.substring(shashLoc, underLoc);
    } else return "";
}
```

Comment: unintuitively, it's longer code but yes, it should be faster.